# como ver o SQL executado pelo sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server

Eu executo o seguinte código:

```
$sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[NOTA_FISCAL] 
        SET [STATUS] = ?,
            [USUARIO]= ?,
            DATA_TRATAMENTO = (getdate()),
            [MOTIVO_CANCELAMENTO] = ?
        WHERE [ID_NOTA_FISCAL] = ?";
$params = [2,30,'',7];      
$options= ["Scrollable" => "forward", 'QueryTimeout' => 60];
sqlsrv_query($this->MSconn, $sql, $params, $options);
```

Gostaria de ver o SQL que é executado no banco pelo `sqlsrv_query` , pois apesar de na minha cabeça está tudo certo ele não está executando no banco de dados.

Tem como habilitar para ele gerar o *log* das consultas executadas ou algo do tipo?

atualmente contornei o **bug** desconectando e conectando novamente a base de dados, contudo ver o SQL rodado na base seria interessante.

Comment: Chega aparecer algum erro? pode usara  função `sqlsrv_errors()`

Comment: não, não chega a apresentar nenhum erro. logo apos eu tenho um if (($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) que não entra.

Comment: contornei o problema desconectando e conectando novamente, mas queria mesmo um jeito de visualizar qual o SQL ele está executando